# Clear Gridview each time click a button

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My code populate 1st row inside the grid view. After page loads and type 1st row data I can populate 10 rows by click the copyButton. but when I change 1st row data and click again it shows 20 rows. But I need only 10 rows that has only updated data which is new entry. How can I update grid view when i click second time by deleting the old record and populated by 1st new entered values?

Example:

```
ID  Explanation  teacher
--- ----         --------
0   hello        45       
1   hello        45
2   hello        45
.   .            .
.   .            .
.   .            .
10  hello        45
```

=======================================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this line immediately before the `for` loop to clear the collection of rows in the `DataGridView`:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

Then you can probably remove this line *(if I'm understanding what you're trying to do):*

```
dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
```

Also, you said you want 10 rows, but you're inserting 16 in your loop. Might want to double-check that.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that, `dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();` only clears Rows in DataGridView. If you want to clear whole Table (Rows and Columns) and `dataGridView1.DataSource = null` doesn't work (If your Data is not bound by Table) 
try this:
`dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();`